# Find unused indexes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there a good way to profile a MongoDB instance in production, to see which indexes are being used in the queries it is serving over some time period (an hour, a few days, whatever). We have a large number of indexes across various collections and it is challenging to know with certainty across a large code and team which are being used. I suspect a number could be removed but it is quite dangerous to try removing them in a production environment. Thanks!